# Applying @Around aspect to @Slf4j

Tags: spring, aspectj, slf4j

Is it possible to apply an aspect to a maven dependency? I have other aspects in my project that work just fine, but when I try to apply this one to the `@Slf4j` logger it gets skipped. I determined that the pointcut was `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.*` by debugging and stepping into the log.info call but it still wont trigger the aspect. Is there a setting to enable it on dependencies?

The other commented out pointcuts are the ones i've tried but they either cause beans to fail to be created (they're not eligible to be processed by bean post processors) or don't do anything.

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Around("execution(* ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.*(..))"// && " +
//            "execution(* lombok.*(..)) && " +
//            "execution(* org.slf4j.*(..)) && " +
//            "execution(* org.slf4j.Logger.*(..)) "
    )
    public Object prependBridgeRunId(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        //get original args
        Object[] args = jp.getArgs();

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            Object raw = args[i];
            if (raw instanceof String) {
                // and replace it with a new value
                args[i] = "{\"bridgeRunId\": " + GlobalConstants.getBridgeRunId() + "}" + raw;
            }
        }

        //execute original method with new args
        return jp.proceed(args);
    }
}
```

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Sleuth automatically adds trace interceptors when in the classpath -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
                <version>${sleuth.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
                <version>${logstash.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!--FOR TRUSTING SELF SIGNED CERTS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--FOR TRUSTING SELF SIGNED CERTS-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.9.7</version> -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
            <artifactId>value</artifactId>
            <version>${immutables.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON LOGBACK CONFIG -START -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.contrib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.contrib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON LOGBACK CONFIG -END -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8.RC1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8.RC1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.checkstyle.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>checkstyle</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.info.report.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <!--                <includes>-->
                <!--                    <include>**/*.json</include>-->
                <!--                </includes>-->
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>something.else.BusinessRules</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</outputDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <weaveDependencies>
                        <weaveDependency>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        </weaveDependency>
                    </weaveDependencies>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please follow the advice I already gave to you on GitHub and show me your POM. I wan to see how you compile your aspects so far, then I can just tell you the delta. I also want to know if you are currently using proxy-based Spring AOP or native AspectJ, because with Spring AOP what you want is impossible while with AspectJ you can do it. Ideally, push an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to GitHub, so I can see your Spring configuration, too. Like this, there are too many open questions.

Comment: @kriegaex Since @Slf4j/logback is not registered to be a Spring bean I don't think I can use the spring aspectj. So I was attempting to use the native AspectJ. But It didn't seem to work. p.s. POM added

Comment: I will try to get a MCVE working, Thank  you for your help!

Comment: I wrote a generic answer already, explaining some basics. As soon as I have the MCVE, I can be more specific and solve your problem directly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that the old Mojohaus plugin version even supports Java 11, Java 8 should be the maximum. Please use a more up-to-date version (1.14.0) or - even better - switch to my own fork, which I am maintaining in parallel to maintaining AspectJ itself: https://github.com/dev-aspectj/aspectj-maven-plugin. Version 1.13.1 supports Java 17 and can be configured to also support future Java and AspectJ versions without requiring a plugin update. Tooling for Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA also works for this plugin.

Furthermore, when using post-compile binary weaving for third-party libraries, please be aware of the fact that the woven files will end up in your Maven module's target directory and packaged together with your artifact. In order to avoid having both the woven and unwoven variants of the same class files on the classpath, either make sure not to depend on the original during runtime or simply do the binary weaving in a separate Maven module and then depending on that module instead of the original library. That would be the cleanest solution.

As an alternative to post-compile weaving, you could simply use load-time weaving as describes in the Spring manual, chapter [Using AspectJ with Spring Applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj). Then you do not need to use AspectJ Maven Plugin at all, as long as you stick to annotation-based syntax and do not use native Aspectj syntax at all.

By the way, no matter if you use post-compile or load-time weaving, in neither case do you need to declare your aspect to be a Spring `@Component`. That might even have the negative side-effect of Spring trying to apply it as a Spring AOP aspect, even though it was already woven as a native AspectJ aspect.

Comment: I was under the impression that using the spring version of aspectj could only be used on methods of objects that are beans?

Comment: There is no "Spring version of AspectJ". There is either Spring AOP or AspectJ. We are talking about the latter here, so why are you asking about the former out of context? What do you actually want to know?

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding there, thank you for your clarification!

Comment: Maybe you were referring to my remark that Spring AOP can pick up an AspectJ aspect if it is also declared as a `@Component`. This can actually happen, so like I said, better remove the Spring component annotation when using a native AspectJ aspect. Otherwise, if your pointcut matches both Spring components and non-spring stuff, both AOP frameworks would try to use the same aspect. Better safe than sorry.